# How to git stage a just-tangled file in `org-babel-post-tangle-hook`

Tags: org-mode, magit, git, projectile

I want to create a `org-babel-post-tangle-hook` that does a `git stage buffer-file-name`.  There is a boring technical issue I have, which is that I don't know how to call `magit-stage-file` from elisp so that it doesn't prompt me to save. There's some way to wrap my call to `magit-stage-file` to accomplish this that I haven't figured out yet.  Then there's the second issue of getting this to work across different settings.  For example, I would like to be able to have this work even in the case that `buffer-file-name` is in a different git repo than the one I'm currently working out of. The `buffer-file-name` might even be on a different machine (over TRAMP)Could projectile be of use here?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Drew.  The sub-question about calling interactive functions non-interactively is (strictly) an elisp question though, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not a candidate for tag `elisp`; it's not about the design of the language itself. It's a question about how to do something using Elisp. And BTW, the particular question of how to call a command non-interactively has already been posed, including recently.